# How to get actual list of Outlook accounts in Add-In after adding or removing an account by user?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

My Add-In should change its mode if the list of accounts is changed.

I get the list of outlook accounts the following way:

```
var ns = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
accounts = ns.Accounts;
```

It works, but when user adds new account or remove some of them, the **ns.Accounts** still shows old value. It's changed only if I reload outlook. 
Also I have been searching events for adding and removing accounts and still can't find.

Could you please help me?

Comment: So it is not reloaded if you read the namespace again?

Comment: @Nico Thank you for response.No, it is not reloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no events that occur in the Outlook Object Model when accounts are modified.  You have to restart Outlook in order to see the changes.  The only other related option is to monitor the Stores.StoreAdd event if the user opens or adds a Data File to the profile, but that's probably not useful for your needs.

Otherwise you can use a third-party library like Redemption, which can monitor changes to Accounts: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccounts.htm#events

Comment: Thank you, Stores.StoreAdd event works fine for my needs!